# Check for diff on update

Tags: svn

I installed fresh copy of svn from ubuntu repositiory. Version is 1.6.12.

Now, for example, lets say there are two users: User1 and User2.

Day1.

1. Any of users imports new project. Project consists of 1 file: main.cpp.
2. Both users make checkout, now they both have working copies.

Day2.

1. User1 comes to work,deletes everything from main.cpp, commits and goes home.
2. User2 comes to work after User1 left updates and he get empty main.cpp from repository without any prompts of conflicts.

So the question if is it possible to tune svn so it prompts on conflict on update in situation as described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no conflict unless *User2* also made a change before updating.

`svn update` simply means that the working copy is updated with the latest revision from the repository. So it is expected (and intended) behavior that the empty file (which is the latest revision of the file) is fetched into the working copy.

Comment: More clean: "...changes from repo (all and any) are distributed to working copies"

Comment: Ok. i get it. Thanks. But what should user2 do to resolve conflicts before updating? Not only when file is empty. But in general when there are several differences between his version and server version?

Comment: Hi Alexander, when `svn update` recognizes a conflict (i.e. *User2* made a change and *User1* committed a changed file before) it informs the user (status flag `C`). Furthermore it populates several files to *User2s* working copy: The current revision from repository, the base revision of *User2s* edited file, the changed file of *User2* and a merged file containing sections with conflict markers as well as automatically resolved parts. *User2* can then `diff` those (at least) four files, merge them (i.e. solve the conflicts) and commit the merged file.

Answer (score 2):

> in situation as described above?

There are not conflicts,  because user2 doesn't have any local changes, which *can* produce conflict and require manual-merge